# Any ideas how I can shorten this code?

Tags: c#, mysql, select

```
string menuRecipe = "SELECT * FROM recipelist WHERE menu_ID = '" + menuID + "'";
MySqlCommand recipeCmd = new MySqlCommand(menuRecipe, db.mycon);
MySqlDataReader recipeDr = recipeCmd.ExecuteReader();
string[] info = new string[8];
while (recipeDr.Read())
{
    info[1] = (recipeDr["recipe_ID"].ToString());
    info[2] = (recipeDr["stock_ID"].ToString());
    info[4] = (recipeDr["recipe_quantity"].ToString());
    string stockName = "SELECT stock_name FROM stocksdb WHERE stock_ID = '" + info[2] + "'";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(stockName, db.mycon);
    MySqlDataReader nameDr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (nameDr.Read())
    {
        info[3] = (nameDr["stock_name"].ToString());
    }
    this.recipeList.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4] }));
}
```

I primarily want to reduce having to use multiple SQL command strings, though I don't know how, and how I could segregate them into their respective places since some may get jumbled up.

Comment: Guys, may I ask for a good link?

Comment: This can be done very easily with a DataReader.  I'm confused at what your code is trying to accomplish.  What is your relationship between recipelist and stocksdb.  Are you expecting more than one result from the recipelist query?  Are you expecting more than one result from the stocksdb query?  If not, why are they in a where statement instead of an if statement?  Also, it's a bad habit to concatenate sql strings -- you should use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: String concatenation for SQL is a bad idea; it's a recipe for SQL injection.  You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: I guess the other guy was right. The one who said I can use one connection I used for one dataReader on another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your query to

```
SELECT r.*, s.stock_name FROM recipelist r
LEFT OUTER JOIN stocksdb s ON r.stock_ID = s.stock_ID
WHERE menu_ID = @parameter
```

Comment: Okay I'll try this one. But may I ask what 'r.' and 's.' stands for?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe they are alias for tables recipelist and stocksdb

Answer (score 2):

You could do an INNER JOIN in your initial query to link the stocksdb table to your recipe list table on stock_ID.

Comment: May I ask how that would look like?

Answer (score 2):

I would change your code to something like this:

```
string connect = "...";
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connect))
{
    cn.Open();

    string sql = @"
SELECT r.*, s.stock_name 
FROM recipelist r
LEFT OUTER JOIN stocksdb s ON r.stock_ID = s.stock_ID
WHERE menu_ID = @MenuID";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MenuID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = menuID;
    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        this.recipeList.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { 
            dr["recipe_ID"].ToString(), 
            dr["stock_ID"].ToString(), 
            dr["stock_name"].ToString(), 
            dr["recipe_quantity"].ToString()
        }));
    }
}
```